# cast left side of expression predicate into string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, predicate

i am having a generic method which return an expression predicate to filter data from list.

```
   MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.ColumnName);
                    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.TextToBeFiltered);

                    switch (filter.FilterOperation)
                    {
                        case FilterEnum.Equals:
                            return Expression.Equal(member, constant);
    }
     var res = List.Where(reqExpression).ToList();
```

Problem is the properties in list some of are string,int,guid etc so i want to cast left side of expression into string because i need to compare all properties with string only like `a=> a.Id.tostring() == inputstring`so how to perform it in my code.

Comment: You need to get the `MethodInfo` for the `ToString` method and `Expression.Call` it on the individual objects

Comment: can you show me some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this full example:

```
class Program
{
    class MyType
    {
        public int Column { get; set; }
    };

    public static string AsString(object obj)
    {
        return obj?.ToString();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyType));
        //your member
        MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, "Column");
        var asString = typeof(Program).GetMethod("AsString");
        var stringMember = Expression.Call(asString, Expression.Convert(member, typeof(object)));
        //your value
        ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant("23");
        //your switch
        var expression = Expression.Equal(stringMember, constant);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(expression, param);
        var list = new List<MyType>
        {
            new MyType{Column = 23},
            new MyType{Column= 24}
        };
        var res = list.Where((Func<MyType,bool>)lambda.Compile()).ToList();
    }
}
```

You can also use `ToString` method (beware `null`s!) or `Convert.ChangeType`. Own `AsString` method is good for custom types and... for debugging.

Think as building code:

```
p => AsString((object)p.Column) == "23"
```